# jquery autocomplete doesn't clear Unordered List

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

My code is:

```
        $("#contactSearch").autocomplete({
            source: "bulk_GetContacts.php",
            minLength: 4,
            delay: 100
        })          
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            console.log(ul);
            return $( "<li class=\"ui-state-highlight\"></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo("#autocompleteResults");

        };
```

The problem is that when i enter abcd, it correctly shows me the results in my div ("#autocompleteResults"). But when i add 'e' (abcde) it doesn't clear the past results and adds the new ones to the bottom of the div.
How can i clear the list of the past results?

Regards,
Nicos

Comment: use `ul.empty();` before append..

Comment: if i use ul.empty() before append, it will clear the UL every time, so it shows only the last <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line when creating autocomplete. So every time you add something in autocomplete the list is cleared.

```
$("#contactSearch").autocomplete({
                source: "bulk_GetContacts.php",
                minLength: 4,
                delay: 100,
                **search: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#autocompleteResults").empty();
                }**
```